# DocuSign API Embedded in iFrame not updating parent url

Tags: docusignapi

I have DocuSign embedded in iframe and on Finish the url of the parent is not updated.  How can i do so?

I am using twig tempting engine to render the page . if it causes any issues?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45016801/3530898, it seems duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Often better to skip the iframe altogether. Use your software stack's session features to maintain state.

Comment: I am using drupal CMS and have to embed  docSign url return from api call. Not sure if its possible to implement above