# Docusign return parameters in embedded signing by breaking out iframe

Tags: docusignapi

How to pass parameters(`envelope,PF and r ID`) within `iframe` while returning URL in embedded docusigning? If I enter the `POWERFORM` link on browser I'm returning URL with the parameters (`envelope,PF and r ID`) but if I run  code within `iframe` I'm unable to get the parameters. Please do assist me about this issue.

Comment: Can you please explain the issue clearly, you are using embedded signing, and on the return/callback URL, you are using Powerform with some merge fields (envelopeId, RecipientId)? Why you are having a PF as a callback url?

Comment: Amit I have to integrate my web app with embedded signing..I am running HTML code within iframe it will direct customer to sign the document by skipping powerform page. Once customer clicks finish button after signing (1) It should be redirected to new webpage by breaking out of iframe but in my case its redirecting within iframe (even after mentioning new page url in insession landing page) (2) And the second issue is it should display any one of the  return parameters such as envelope ID,PF or r ID so that I can keep reference in my database for the particular document.

Comment: So you are using just Powerform Form, and first signer is the only signer in that Powerform. Ideally we use `embedded signing` terminology with API only, but in your case everything is powerform driven only, no API calls.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening Powerform inside an IFrame, so the scope of the opened URL is inside the IFrame only and DocuSign cannot do anything to redirect the browser to come out of the IFrame. You have write a code on your end to capture the redirect URL and break the flow out of IFrame, you can find a similar query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951027/breaking-out-of-iframe-in-docusign). Normally DocuSign does not recommend using IFrame for Signing, also to capture the data like envelopeId, r Id etc, it is better to configure `DocuSign Connect` with a listener on your side. Using url redirect is a fragile solution as user might close the browser (or browser hangs/network issue) and you might lose the data. Whereas with DS Connect, DocuSign will publish the event to your listener and you will be able to capture all the required data in your listener.

Answer (score 0):

`window.parent.window.location.href = 'Parent URL'` works to break out of an iframe and load the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script>
        function myFunction()
        {
        var x = document.getElementById("form1").action;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; 
        }
    </script>
```

This thing works for displaying the parameters.

Comment: <body onload="myFunction()">
        <p id="demo"></p>

            <script>
            function myFunction()
            {
            var x = document.getElementById("form1").action;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; 
            }
        </script>