# Docusign return URL with any one of the parameter

Tags: docusignapi

I have to integrate my web app with Docusign embedded signing.

I am running HTML code within iframe it will direct customer to sign the document by skipping powerform page.

Once customer clicks finish button after signing:

1. It should be redirected to new webpage by breaking out of iframe but in my case its redirecting within iframe itself (even after mentioning new page url in insession landing page)
2. And the second issue is it should display any one of the return parameters such as envelope ID, PF or ID so that I can keep reference in my database for the particular document for future reference.

Comment: Why a duplicate post is created, when you already have asked same qs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450146/docusign-return-parameters-in-embedded-signing-by-breaking-out-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Using a Powerform from your app is essentially a one-way maneuver: once you redirect the user to the Powerform, you can't get him or her back, AFAIK.

What is your use case? Is the signer someone within your organization? Who is the sender of the signing request? (You should edit your question, not add the info vai a comment.)

If your use case is that someone comes to your web app, fills out a form, and then wants to sign it, then you can either:

1. Redirect the person to the Powerform at the end of their interaction with your website. After they finish signing, they are "done." Your app can subscribe (via Connect) to learn the envelope ID that was used.
2. Use a Powerform in an iFrame with a big button above the iFrame marked **Return to the app** -- This solution is **highly not recommended** since it is a poor user experience and won't work on a mobile device.
3. **Recommended:** Create a custom envelope/signing request for the web app visitor by using Service Integration authentication with DocuSign. Then present an embedded signing ceremony to the web app visitor so they can sign. After the embedded signing ceremony, your web app will be redirected to by DocuSign so your app will regain control of the session. No iFrame is needed in this pattern either.

Answer (score 0):

PowerForms uses the In-Session Landing Page configured on your DocuSign account.  When complete, the browser will be redirected there and will append a set of parameters - importantly the envelope ID.  It can also include Custom Envelope Fields if you need them.

Popping out of the iFrame is the responsibility of your HTML pages.  Your landing page can include javascript that will do the job.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action) lists various methods but typically you want something like:

```
<script>
window.top.location = "htttp://myreal.landing/page"
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff..I am working on docusign using powerform within iframe. I added java script to my HTML on the return url page as a result all the parameters(envelope,pf and r ID) are displaying. If second user signs the document return page should be displayed with unique parameters I mean dynamically but its displaying the same parameters. Please do assist regarding this issue.