# How to close iframe when control returns to returnurl when click on send button of Docusign tagging interface loaded with-in iframe?

Tags: docusignapi

I am implementing docusign embedded sending, so I have opened the tagging interface in iframe in my web application,
It loads perfectly in iframe but now when user clicks on send button inside tagging interface I wanted to fire one javascript function that will close the iframe but it is not happening I have tried several jquery solutions but it does not work,
When I bind the click event on that button class in tagging interface with below code

```
<iframe id="taggingInterface" width="100%" height="100%" class="absoluteDiv radius6" src="${embeddedSignURL}" frameborder="0"></iframe>

var iframe = $j('#taggingInterface').contents();
iframe.find("button.btn").click(function(){
   alert("test");
});
```

**it throws error like 
Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://mohiz.local.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.**

Comment: As Larry mentioned, best is not to use IFrame, as that gives bad user experience for the signer, mainly on the mobile platform. But if you want to continue using the IFrame, then solution for your problem is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951027/breaking-out-of-iframe-in-docusign)

Answer (score 0):

Best is to not use an iframe. Redirect to DocuSign and then DocuSign will redirect back to you.

Why do you think an iframe is the best way to go?